# iOS - How to deal with spaces in a file name

Tags: ios

if I have a file called "test document.doc", I can retrieve it as test%20document.doc and if i wanna store it in an array, it will give me an error.. how can I retrieve the file name as is?

Comment: Just use the file name as it is...what do you mean "you can retrieve it"...it is probably giving you an error because you are trying to insert `nil` into an NSArray.

Comment: If you have control over the filenames, I'd say just not to use spaces at all...  Not that this answers your question, but it's my recommendation as to the proper course of action.

Comment: @borrrden what happens is that I get the URL `fileURL = [self.documentURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` then when I try to remove it, it gives an error because the file doesnt exist ` [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[trimPath lastObject] error:NULL];`

Comment: That information would have been useful in your question don't you think?  Also information on how you are actually creating the URL...this question actually lacks a lot of info....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the URL instead of the path.

```
removeItemAtPATH:
```

it takes a path not a URL